# Magento2 Innermost category selection as Radio Button

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

like we have check-boxes for selecting category for products, but for a specific requirement I want to limit the selection of innermost category to just one instead of multiple.

**for example** `parent->chilld->multiple child`

so what I want is from Multiple child just one can be selected even if it is checkbox.